# Find any number not in the list

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to find any number not in the list. It can be negative or positive value. Take a look at the table below:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | sorder | Name                |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2      | Chevy               |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 2  | 78     | Michilin            |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 3  | -34    | XM                  |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 4  | 97     | Manual Transmission |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 5  | 3911   | Halogen             |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Given this query result I must find any number that is not in `sorder`. `sorder` can be any negative or positive number. If possible I'd like to use sql to find the result. Here is my desired resultset:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | sorder | Name                |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2      | Chevy               |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 2  | 78     | Michilin            |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 3  | -34    | XM                  |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 4  | 97     | Manual Transmission |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 5  | 3911   | Halogen             |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 6  | 690    | Valvoline 5w30      |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide desired resultset

Comment: You could just find the maximum and add 1...

Comment: where to get the `690 Valvoline 5w30` from ?

Comment: Your desired result set includes all the numbers in the given result set, but you said you want any number not in 'sorder'? Why would you not just ignore the given list and select the whole table?

Comment: Sorry, for the limited explaination. Basically, I am trying to assign a temp value to sorder. I can't use max + 1 because another thread may assign that value. To make matters worse I am not allowed to lock the table so I can't use max. I was thinking maybe I can choose a random number from -32B and 32B. But I am not sure how often the number will collide. I am estimating that each dataset will be no more than 1000 records.

Comment: @Squirrel I just need the sorder number. I am inserting data in the table but when I perform the insert the sorder cannot be the same as the other sorder numbers.

Comment: @Luke101 If the values do not have to be random you could use **[`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)** `INSERT INTO tab( sorder, Name)  SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySeq, 'Valvoline 5w30'`;

Comment: @Luke101 [Demo](http://rextester.com/FYV54581)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `List`, you could do either of these.

**Option 1**

As **Jon Skeet** pointed in list, take the `Max` and add 1.

```
int maxSOrder = objecList.Max(s=>s.sorder);
int nextIndex = maxSOrder +1;
```

**Option 2**

If you are looking for a solution to find minimum available index from the minimum number, you could do this.

```
int minSOrder = objecList.Min(s=>s.sorder);
int maxSOrder = objecList.Max(s=>s.sorder);
int minNotInList = Enumerable.Range(minSOrder, maxSOrder-minSOrder)
                             .FirstOrDefault(f=> !objectList.Any(o=>o.sorder == f);

if(minNotInList ==0)  // just fallback logic, when default is used
{ 
    minNotInList = maxSOrder +1; 
}
```